# PHP not working as expected

Tags: php, html

I have a simple form calling a `PHP` script upon submit but it does not work as expected. It just takes me back to `'localhost:8080'` without any error messages which is not even there in the `PHP` script. Please have a look at the code below and tell me how do I correct this. Also I had the below form as `POST` initially but it was not working at all, i.e., the php file was not getting the post data. I switched to `GET`, it worked for some time and now even this is not working. It may very well be some settings problem. I am using `WAMP x64` on `Windows 7 x64` and have not modified any setting.

This is my form -

```
<form role="form" action="/login.php" method="GET">
                    <div class="form-group">
                      <label for="email">Email:</label>
                      <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="username@xyz.com" name="email">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                      <label for="password">Password:</label>
                      <input type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="password" name="password">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                      <label><a href="/forgot-password">Forgot Password?</a></label>
                      <label><a href="/new-user"> New User?</a></label>
                    </div>
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary center-block">Submit</button>
                </form>
```

This is the `PHP` file -

```
<?php
if (isset($_SESSION)) {
    header("location: http://localhost:8080/home");
} else {
    if (isset($_GET['email']) and isset($_GET['password'])) {

        $email = $_GET['email'];
        $pass = $_GET['password'];

        $con = mysqli_connect('localhost','read','*****','sheet_db');

        if(mysqli_connect_errno()) {
            header("location: http://localhost:8080/?message=internal%20error");
        } else {
            $check = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT COUNT(emp_id) as cnt FROM d_emp WHERE emp_email = '".$email."' AND password = '".$pass."'");
            if(mysqli_fetch_array($check)['cnt'] == 1) {
                session_start();
                $_SESSION['email']=$email;
                header("location: http://localhost:8080/home");
            } else {
                header("location: http://localhost:8080/?message=wrong%20username%20or%20password");
            }
        }
    } else {
        header("location: http://localhost:8080/?message=invalid%20parameters");
    }
}

?>
```

Comment: did you check the process gets as far as the else part of the if-loop? Did you check the values?

Comment: Yes if I add echo statements and remove location headers, it does run as expected. Just the headers are not doing their job.

Comment: @user3162834 does it redirects to `http://localhost:8080/?message=internal%20error`???

Comment: It redirects to 'http://localhost:8000'

Comment: Related; You will want to check out [this question about SQL Injection](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php?rq=1) It's an extremely dangerous problem, and your code is vulnerable to it.

Comment: Okay so I replaced all location headers with echo statements and now everything works as expected. Getting the right echo output for every case. What do you think is wrong with the headers above?

Answer (score 1):

Change `action="/login.php"` to `action="./login.php"` then let me know if it solves your problem.

Comment: and if this script is being run in a subdir and the login script really is in the document root?

Comment: @MarcB Lets see what OP says!

Comment: Both the files are in document root. If I remove all php location headers, it does go to login.php.